# Error in DBT cloud Server error: Database Error in rpc request (from remote system) syntax error at or near ")"

Tags: sql, union, dbt, dbt-utils, fishtown-analytics

```
WITH unioned_product_reports AS(
    {% set prod_relations = dbt_utils.get_relations_by_pattern('xyz_shema', 'test_products%') %}
    {{ dbt_utils.union_relations(relations = prod_relations) }}
    ranking_product_report_rows AS(
        SELECT *,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date, name ORDER BY batch_runtime DESC) rno
        FROM unioned_product_reports
    )
)
```

In dbt I am trying to union all tables by above using above dbt-utils packages but it showing error as:

> Server error: Database Error in rpc request (from remote system)
> syntax error at or near ")" LINE 13: )

can someone suggest solution.

Comment: Does the SELECT statement work if you run it directly against your DB rather than via DBT?

Comment: Is this the whole model?  If so I think it's missing a `SELECT * FROM ranking_product_report_rows`

edit: it also seems like the first CTE might be missing a `),` at the end...

Comment: @JoshD. Yeah, I am doing select * from ranking_product_rows but the error comes before that in `WITH unioned_product_reports AS` this block only

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which database you are connecting to. I had the same error when connecting to Snowflake and fixed it with:

> Go to the top right corner and click "settings gear",
> Go to profile settings,
> Go to credentials,
> Under credentials, select the Profile you are working on

- Right slide menu will pop

> Scroll down to development credentials and click the green connect snowflake account button. Or add the credentials you are using to connect to the respective DB. For me Snowflake,
> it should reconnect your snowflake authentication and you should be good to go

Hope it helps